# how to open child form in WPF window with DevExpresss ribbon control

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, mdi

I am trying to open a form as child in WPF window. I want to open it as a MDI child. I used to do it in Forms but I couldnt do it in WPF.

My WPF window is like below

[image]

When the user clicks "Database" button, I want to open the form in the container. How can I do it in WPF?

here is ItemClick event of Database button... this code opens it as a popup which I dont want

```
private void btnDatabase_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    frmDatabase frm = new frmDatabase();
    frm.Show();
}
```

Comment: There are at least a couple of ways to contain child views. 1) Put a Frame in your main window and set it's content to the "child" page. This approach is one child at a time. 2) Create a Tab Control in your main window where each tab item contains the "child" page. This approach will allow you to have multiple contained views (per tab item), but you have to manage creating and closing the tab items on the fly.

Comment: Have you tried [DevExpress Dock Windows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6191)?